# Keyword -new- before method implementation

Tags: c#, methods, new-operator

What does -new- keyword mean here?

```
  class X
  {
        new byte Method ()
        {
              return 5;
        }
  }
```

I found some on stackoverflow, but I need simpliest answer as possible (poor english).

Comment: In the above code case it does not make much sense of using new keyword actually. Because its not inheriting any other class except System.Object (by default).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new` hides the method from the base class:

```
class Base
{ 
    byte Method () 
    { 
          return 4; 
    } 
} 

class X : Base
{ 
    new byte Method () 
    { 
          return 5; 
    } 
} 

X x = new X();
Base b = x;
Console.WriteLine(x.Method()); // Prints "5"
Console.WriteLine(b.Method()); // Prints "4"
```

Significantly, if the method is virtual, and you use `override` instead of `new`, the behavior is different:

```
class Base
{ 
    virtual byte Method () 
    { 
          return 4; 
    } 
} 

class X : Base
{ 
    override byte Method () 
    { 
          return 5; 
    } 
} 

X x = new X();
Base b = x;
Console.WriteLine(x.Method()); // Prints "5"
Console.WriteLine(b.Method()); // Prints "5"
```

Answer (score 1):

Its the [new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword. If used on a method it hides an existing inherited method.

In your case since `X` doesn't derive from any class you will get a warning saying the `new` keyword doesn't hide any existing methods.

Also the method is private (by default) and cannot be accessed outside the class.

If `X` does derive from a class that has that method, it will hide it. @phoog has excellent examples in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

also see this topic: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fawty39%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)